# DELPHI XE3 ADO Query makes my Application freeze while it waits for data

Tags: delphi, ado

Is there any solution so as not to get my UI frozen while it waits for data to come from the Database ??

Example:

We have an adoquery and we do

adoquery.active:=false; 
adoquery.active:=true;

When the adoquery tries to get data from the db everything in the UI is frozen and if the user clicks then the whole program becomes
Not Responding!!

Is there any cure to this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

You might use `[eoAsyncExecute,eoAsyncFetch]` in the `ExecuteOptions`, this will require the Dataset is using an explicit TAdoConnection.
To avoid unexpected behavior you will have to use `DisableControls` before opening the Dataset, and `EnableControls` after `FetchComplete`.
A direct called `EnableControls` within `FetchComplete` may cause Exceptions, so using Postmessage with an user defined Message will be necessary.

```
  Const
  // define a message for handling completed AsyncFetch after leaving FetchComplete
  WM_MYConnect=WM_User + 77;

type

  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    MyDataSet: TADODataSet;
    MyDatasource: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyDataSetFetchComplete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    Procedure ConnectDatasource(var MSG:TMessage); message WM_MYConnect;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  MyForm: TMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyDataset.Close;
 // example blocking command for SQL-Server 10 seconds
 MyDataset.CommandText := 'WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:10'' Select* from  aa';
 Mydataset.DisableControls;
 Mydataset.ExecuteOptions := [eoAsyncExecute,eoAsyncFetch];
 MyDataset.Open;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ConnectDatasource(var MSG:TMessage);
begin
   TAdodataset(MSG.WParam).EnableControls;
//   MyDataSource.DataSet := MyDataset;
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyDataSetFetchComplete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
begin
  // if we want to add a datasource we will have to ensure that it will happen after leaving FetchComplete
  // so we call our procedure ConnectDatasource via PostMessage
  PostMessage(Handle,WM_MYConnect,wParam(DataSet),0);
end;

end.
```